# Al realizar cambios en HTML o CSS no se ven en la pagina

Tags: html, css, firefox, cache, chrome

Cuando hago modificaciones a una pagina web que ya esta en funcionamiento, los usuarios finales por el tema del cache del navegador, no ven los cambios inmediatamente hasta que Limpian la Cache del navegador o entran en modo incógnito.

Habrá alguna solución para que al realizar cambios en HTML o CSS estos se reflejen inmediatamente al entrar a la web sin necesidad de Limpiar Cache, Entrar en Modo incógnito, usar el Network/Disbled Cache de google chrome (El cual no funciona la mayoría de las veces) o instalar alguna extensión que limpie la cache??

Answer (score 2):

En HTML puedes hacer uso de las siguientes etiquetas en tu `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

<meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">

<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">

<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

---

En PHP puedes lograrlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1

header("Expires: Sat, 1 Jul 2000 05:00:00 GMT"); // Fecha en el pasado

?>
```

---

Incluso puedes modificar tu `.htaccess`:

```
## Fecha de expiracion de cache ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
## fin cache ##
```

---

Puedes consultar información sobre los meta tags [aquí](http://vancouver-webpages.com/META/metatags.detail.html), también tienes [este sitio](https://www.metatags.org/meta_http_equiv) con más detalles sobre el meta tag `HTTP-EQUIV`

Comment: Acabo de intentar con la solución HTML y no me funciona, sigo modificando el HTML, voy a la Web, le doy F5 y no aparece, a menos que vaya a modo incógnito o limpie el cache. Sera que el .htaccess lo soluciona?

Comment: Los navegadores siempre complican las cosas, el código para `.htaccess` no debe fallar